# Means of transportation in the case of Jephthah and his daughter

Tags: hebrew-bible, judges

Can we infer from the Bible passage below (or from other sources) that Jephthah was passing the lengths of the territory on his legs or rather there is the possibility for other means of transportation? Also, is there any possibility that Jephthah's daughter left the house riding on an animal (with other people), and then in a closer proximity to his father she started to dance and play the tambourine along with people who accompanied her? Would it be possible in that case, that the animal she was riding was burnt as a holocaust offering, and she remained a virgin and devoted her life to the Lord?

> "Then the Spirit of the LORD was upon Jephthah, and he passed through
>   Gilead and Manasseh and passed on to Mizpah of Gilead, and from Mizpah
>   of Gilead he passed on to the Ammonites. And Jephthah made a vow to
>   the LORD and said, “If you will give the Ammonites into my hand, then
>   whatever comes out from the doors of my house to meet me when I return
>   in peace from the Ammonites shall be the LORD’s, and I will offer it
>   up for a burnt offering.” So Jephthah crossed over to the Ammonites to
>   fight against them, and the LORD gave them into his hand. And he
>   struck them from Aroer to the neighborhood of Minnith, twenty cities,
>   and as far as Abel-keramim, with a great blow. So the Ammonites were
>   subdued before the people of Israel.
>
> Then Jephthah came to his home at Mizpah. And behold, his daughter
>   came out to meet him with tambourines and with dances. She was his
>   only child; besides her he had neither son nor daughter. And as soon
>   as he saw her, he tore his clothes and said, “Alas, my daughter! You
>   have brought me very low, and you have become the cause of great
>   trouble to me. For I have opened my mouth to the LORD, and I cannot
>   take back my vow.” And she said to him, “My father, you have opened
>   your mouth to the LORD; do to me according to what has gone out of
>   your mouth, now that the LORD has avenged you on your enemies, on the
>   Ammonites.” So she said to her father, “Let this thing be done for me:
>   leave me alone two months, that I may go up and down on the mountains
>   and weep for my virginity, I and my companions.” So he said, “Go.”
>   Then he sent her away for two months, and she departed, she and her
>   companions, and wept for her virginity on the mountains. And at the
>   end of two months, she returned to her father, who did with her
>   according to his vow that he had made. She had never known a man, and
>   it became a custom in Israel that the daughters of Israel went year by
>   year to lament the daughter of Jephthah the Gileadite four days in the
>   year." [Judges 11:29-40 (ESV)]

Comment: In spite of the additional context, I don't think this is substantially a different question from one already on the site: "[Did Jephthah actually sacrifice his daughter?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1227/)"

Comment: @Davïd Bluesky originally posted these questions as an "answer" to the other question - something along the lines of "What I don't understand is ...    Is it possible ...?"  As such, if you feel the "riding on an animal" part is covered by the existing answers, can you point out which one for the benefit of Bluesky?

Comment: @ThaddeusB - Ah, I see it now. I still think it would work better as a properly worked-up answer to the previous Q&A, rather than hived off as a new question. The suggestion in this "Question" provides an answer to the previous one, of course. (IMO, FWIW, YMMV, etc.)